# is it possible to giveAmazon root user giving full access to a user for a particular location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i'm a root user for my AWS account and i want to give my full root access to a particular user(user1 is my user which i created from my root account) *"only for a particular region"*. The user can create new users, groups and also can access to all AWS services only in that region (ex: us-east-1).
is it possible to give an access to a user?

I tried in the JSON and visual editor also, but it is working only for EC2 but user need to access all the root admin permissions only in that particular region.

Thank you

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restrict-ec2-iam/

Comment: it is working for only ec2 service in one region but user need to access to all AWS services for that one region.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to restrict an IAM user/role to use a single region for EC2 service because there is no available [condition key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actionsconditions.html) for other services. Also note that there are several services which are global e.g. IAM, Route53 etc.

Regardless of regions, there can only be one Root user in an account but you can create IAM users with administrator access which will have full access but to do certain tasks, you still need Root credentials (please refer to the [comparison](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html)).